# ajax no me carga la imagen ni audio tipo file

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

hola que tal buenas tardes tengo una duda no me carga la imagen ni audio de tipo file cuando le doy enviar  mi ventana modal nadamas me guarda el nombre Mixe y nombre Espanol y no me guarda la imagen ni audio... gracias

este es mi codigo js y mi form

```
                                <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" id="form1"
                                    action="${actionUrl}" modelAttribute="palabra" role="form">
                                    <div style="width: 60%;">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="imagen" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Imagen:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen"
                                                    id="imagen" placeholder="imagen">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nombreMixe" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Palabra
                                                Mixe:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreMixe"
                                                    id="nombreMixe" placeholder="nombreMixe">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nombreEspanol" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Palabra
                                                Español:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                    name="nombreEspanol" id="nombreEspanol"
                                                    placeholder="nombreEspanol">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="audio" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Audio:</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="audio"
                                                    id="audio" placeholder="audio">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="float-right">
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                data-dismiss="modal" value="Cerrar" />

                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="enviar" 
                                                value="Enviar" />
                                        </div>
                                         <div id="respuesta"><!-- Respuesta AJAX --></div>
                                    </div>  
                                </form>
```

$(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on('submit', '#form1', function() { 
var data = $(this).serialize();

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'agregarPalabras',
        data:data,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Palabras',
    beforeSend:function(){  
 $('#respuesta').html("Insertando datos...");
 },
    success:function(response){
        $('#respuesta').html(data).fadeIn();
```

//          window.location.reload();
            alert('Cambios Realizados Con exito');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
`

Comment: Como puedes ver, tu código no ha salido muy bien representado. Por favor, editalo para que podamos entender mejor la pregunta

Comment: ok gracias solo que no carga  la imagen tipo file en ajax